# Is Fast Search able to extract file metadata?

Tags: crawling, fast-search, ifilter, file-metadata

I was not able to find if Fast Search is able to extract meta data from files. I'm not talking about meta data in the SharePoint document library, but meta data specific to file formats.

Especially :

- image files and Exif data
- Video files and meta data like copyrights, resolution, etc.
- MS office and Open office document.

I'm guessing it's the case, but I did not find the actual answer. I'm also guessing the answer is related to IFilters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FAST Search for SharePoint includes an advanced filter pack which will convert over 200 formats, which is not ifilter based. But I don't think it will do exif meta data.

Office formats on the other hand has meta data extracted.

As for doing exif you can install an ifilter for this, as FS4SP will use ifilters in addition to the advanced filter pack.